# XCode Duplicating Project Schema target , Watch App, Watch App Kit Extension Doesn't work on old project

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, watchapp

I have been trying to Duplicate the Project target, Watch App, and Watch App Kit Extension Doesn't work on the old project as in I created a project in 2018, and at that time I added the watch app and watch kit extension but now due to some requirement changes I have to duplicate Project target, Watch App, Watch App Kit Extension with bundle Id change, Can anyone suggest any proper way to do this because My watch development target is WatchOS 5.1, And iOS development target is 13.0
I have done all the things by duplicating Target and the watch app along with the extension. But I am unable to run copied target Project.

When I try to run a new target, duplicating the main target, it gives me the below error. Any help would be good.

[image]